How to make the swift compiler to remove unused code?
I set up a test project in Xcode and created two SPM targets. The first target depends on the second and uses a class from it, but there is also an unused public function in this class. I compiled the project and profiled the binary file's size using bloaty 1. It shows me that my file (with the class containing the unused public function) SomeClass.swift contributes 708 bytes to the overall size, but after commenting out the unused function, it contributes only 624 bytes.
If I make this unused function internal, SomeClass.swift also contributes 624 bytes.
I concluded that the compiler can omit internal functions because of whole-module optimization and dead code stripping, but it cannot recognize unused public code.
Am I right, and how can I get it to remove public functions?

You cannot know at compile time whether a public function is "used". Even if it is not used in by the other code that you are compiling, some code in the future might use it by linking against the binary you produced.

An what about "-cross-module-optimization" and monolithic LTO option in Xcode?
I thought they are supposed to optimize the whole binary after merging all object files into big one?

That's another question, irrelevant to whether public functions can be removed. Public functions must remain in the binary because they can be called by other binaries.

Try to build with release configuration. It should already have turned on option to strip unused code.

I am building in release mode and all aggressive size optimizations are turned on
